# How to install composer in magento

Tags: magento2, composer

I am trying to install composer using "composer install" from my command terminal display error.[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing to install composer in magento.

By the look of your terminal I am assuming that you are using windows CLI.

You just need to install composer in windows. Here is setup for composer, after installation you will be able to run composer through shell

https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you:

This is one of the way, if you have not installed the composer.

download composer.phar file

```
https://github.com/composer/getcomposer.org/blob/master/web/download/1.0.0-alpha11/composer.phar
```

Place it in magento root directory, then run the command like:

```
php composer.phar YOUR_COMMAND
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to Install and Use Composer on Windows :-**

[Composer Install Step](http://webdevzoom.com/how-to-install-composer-on-windows/)